# Git repo not showing in workspace folder

Tags: eclipse, git, goclipse

Creating a default project in goclipse creates a folder structure with bin, src, and package. I remove the src folder and do a git pull from my remote bare repo and rename it to src. I then delete the project from goclipse and recreate it hoping that it will give me team->commit options on that folder, however the folder is not listed in the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse work with Git, I define/ or import the project from it's location *within the local Git repository*.

For example, my Eclipse workspace is `C:\WS` (short to type, productive!).
I then also have a "Git local repository/ workspace" at `C:\WS Repository` to suit Git's way of working.

I'd suggest you `pull` the remote project into your local Git workspace & then do something like File | Import | Projects from Git.